# Downloaded files are corrupted in IE when requested simultaneously

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, servlets, apache2, download

I am experiencing an awkward problem related with downloading files in Internet Explorer. The server environment is as follows:

- Apache2 as a web server with mod_jk
- Tomcat6 as an application server
- Java/Spring application

The files are served from a Java Servlet. The problem occurs when the certain file is requested from 2 clients using Internet Explorer at the same time. One of the clients fails to get the whole file, and ends up with a corrupt download.

I used Wireshark to see the inbound data. And the download stops at like 50k of a 90k file, with a RELOAD (REsource LOcation And Discovery Framing) request from the server.

This only happens in Internet Explorer. Tried the same scenario with Chrome/Firefox multiple times. And each time the downloads are completed successfully, the files working fine.

I have checked through the application and Apache logs. There are nothing related with this problem. Went through the mod_jk logs with debug level. And it documents that only 50k of the file is sent. But there are no errors logged anywhere about this.

The download servlet is also thread safe, no class variables are used in the doPost()method.

So how to fix or trace the root of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what are the files? what are the file types?

Comment: They are **.pdf** files with different file sizes. But most of them are smaller than 2mb. They do not all stop at 50kb. It is totally random. Sometimes it stops at 17kb, sometimes at 200kb etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was infact a timeout issue. The *TIMEOUT* parameter in apache2 conf file was set to *5* instead of *300*.

When you request a file with IE, the browser asks if you want to download the file or open the file directly. If you wait at that choice screen more than *TIMEOUT*(5) seconds which happens when I am trying to synchronize clicking on the link from 2 computers at the same time, the server sends only a chunk of the file and stops resulting in the corrupt file. But in FF/Chrome, the browser starts the download in the background at a similar choice screen without waiting for your decision.

I had obviously diagnosed the problem completely wrong. But I followed what was reported to me, and while trying to replicating it, the error occured many times, because obviously I was waiting more than 5 seconds in those screens.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information to diagnose the problem, but what I can suggest is to inspect carefully both request headers and resource headers (`Content-Length` and `Content-Type`, as well as any 'esoteric' ones) using both Internet Explorer and (e.g.) Firefox.

I had issues some time ago with an error in the resource supply code, that sent out an incorrect content length. This, somehow, worked in Firefox and Chrome, but resulted in errors with Internet Explorer. Your problem might be similar.

The fact that two (different, as I understand) clients cause the problem makes me think that the issue is server side somehow; some header that only Explorer transmits is hitting some bug you are overlooking. Knowing the header might help locate the bug, or at least supply a hint on how to work around it.

I realise (and concur) )that if the download servlet is "really" thread safe, then it can't be a server issue, but on the other hand, *were the server download chain truly thread safe and invariant, how could the second IE client "know" that it was in fact the second client?*

Comment: All the headers are sent correct. 
I have managed the fixed the issue today, but I was wrong on the definition of the problem (2 clients requesting the same files causes corruption.). It turned out to be a timeout issue. (Explanation in a seperate post)

Answer (score 1):

Usually this problem is resolved by providing correct MIME type with your download script.

But if those pdfs are downloaded from the direct location, then the problem resides in a third party software.

Disable antivirus/antimalware/firewall software and IE plugins, to see if that causes an issue.

Comment: MIME types are correct. The same thing happens when you do not download through the servlet, but enter the relative path of a file.
Tried disabling antivirus already.